Cmder alias command does not support path in space name
I am using the application 'cmder'(version '1.3.19.1181'). I get the error 'Files was unexpected at this time' when i run the below command. I am using cmder . I think this is because of the space before 'Files in the below alias. How do i fix this?
alias lotus="C:\Program Files (x86)\HCL\Notes\notes.exe" 

A possible workaround is to add the command in user_aliases.cmd.  Another possible workaround could be to add the dot3 path without spaces. This works but i want to do this easily from the command line.
